# Refer to column from different table in COUNT() function

Tags: sql, postgresql

The query I am trying to build is essentially this:

```
SELECT a
FROM T1
WHERE T1.b = COUNT(T2.b)
```

but T2 isn't a table that already exists, it's something I have to create using a new SELECT/FROM query, but as far as I know you can't put those in `COUNT()` functions.

How do I make reference to a different table inside the `COUNT()` function? If it makes a difference, I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you post your table structures, some sample data and the required results?

Comment: If you know the select you can simply write it like this: `WHERE T1.b = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2.....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to create using a new SELECT/FROM query, but as far as I know
>   you can't put those in COUNT() functions

You can write `where t1.b = (select count(*)...)` your query would look something like this :

```
SELECT a
FROM T1
WHERE T1.b = (select COUNT(b) from T1 where .. )
```